# Arduino problems with array

Tags: c, arduino

Hi I am working on a project lighting my house lights using an Arduino.

I have it working in a basic form, now I want to store the previous state of the light switch.  I am using an array that stores the current state of the switch so it can be compared on the next loop.  I have 7 switches, I have created it so one switch has the ability to turn on many lights, if required.

I need to store the previous state as the next part is to introduce web control the test project for this is already written

The strange thing is ***zones 7/8 work perfect***.  the other zones turn on, but don't turn off.  When I turn on another switch a light may go off if it's switch is in the off position.

If I remove the condition for the previous state check all switches perfectly fine.

```
const int zone2[] = {8,13,0};
const int zone3[] = {11,0};
const int zone4[] = {7,0};
const int zone5[] = {9,0};
const int zone6[] = {12,0};
const int zone7[] = {6,0};
const int zone8[] = {14,0};

const int * zones[]={zone2,zone3,zone4,zone5,zone6,zone7,zone8};

int buttonState[] = {0,0};         // variable for reading the    pushbutton status

int previousState[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};    // array for holding the previous state of the input button

void setup() 
{
 //initialize the output pins that will control lights

pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);      
pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);

pinMode(11, OUTPUT);      
pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
pinMode(14,OUTPUT);

// initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
//set all light switches to the same block ie pins 30 - 35
byte i; 
//this loop sets all the 30-35pins as inputs 
for (i=30;i< 37;i++) {
pinMode(i, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(i,HIGH);  // this makes it connect to the internal resistor
 }
}

void loop()
{   
 int arrayPosition;
 for (int z = 0; z < 7; ++z)//zero based array needs to be as many as    there are zones!!! 
  {
    buttonState[z] = digitalRead(z+30); 
for (arrayPosition = 0;zones[z][arrayPosition] ; arrayPosition++)
      {
        if ((buttonState[z] == HIGH) ) && (previousState[z] == LOW ))  {   
          // turn LED on:    
          digitalWrite(zones[z][arrayPosition],HIGH); 

          } 
        else if ((buttonState[z] == LOW) && (previousState[z] == HIGH )) {
        // turn LED off;
          digitalWrite(zones[z][arrayPosition],LOW);

          }

    } 
        //each light assigned to the zone has been turned on or off, now set previousstate
        //the statement is here the inner loop has finsihed turning lights on or off that belong to that zone
    previousState[z] = buttonState[z];
  }
}
```

Comment: why does the if condition work when I exclude the previousState.  wouldn't it have the same issue of two elements but accessing seven??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate two elements to the array `buttonState`, but you are accessing seven:

```
[…]
int buttonState[] = {0,0};
[…]
    for (int z = 0; z < 7; ++z)
    {
        buttonState[z] = digitalRead(z+30); 
[…]
```

You should increase the number of elements in the `buttonState` array to be as many as you actually need.

It might be better to define the size of the arrays at a single place:

```
#define NUM_ZONES (7)
[…]
const int * zones[NUM_ZONES]={zone2,zone3,zone4,zone5,zone6,zone7,zone8};

int buttonState[NUM_ZONES] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int previousState[NUM_ZONES]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

[…]
    for (int z = 0; z < NUM_ZONES; ++z)
[…]
```

This will also reveal that your `previousState` array is larger than needed (the compiler will complain that you have too many initialisers for that array). It is then important to re-use that constant everywhere instead of writing the *magic number* `7`.

Comment: why does the if condition work when I exclude the previousState. wouldn't it have the same issue of two elements but accessing seven??

Comment: By writing outside array bounds, you are invoking undefined behaviour. It is possible that you are accidentally writing to the ``previousState`` array when accessing the ``buttonState`` array and modifing its contents in an unpredictable way.